# Why does the select tag not work with a datalist tag?

Tags: html, dom

In HTML5, the [<datalist>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) tag ([Spec](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-datalist-element.html)) was introduced, to be used with `<input>` elements. It contains a set of `<option>` elements, just like the `<select>` tag.

However, using the `<input>` tag allows the user the type their own text, where the dropdown options are kind of like a secondary feature. Whereas the `<select>` tag forces the user to choose one of the defined options.

So I thought: why not create a `<select>` element, and give it a datalist instead of defining each `<option>` seperately. I have a project where I have multiple `select` elements on the same page which share the same set of options, so I thought this would be a nice optimization. However, it doesn't work. It can be tried [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist).

Now this isn't a question about how one could go about doing this, as I think it's pretty clear that it's just not possible at the moment. I couldn't find any libraries to offer a similar feature either. I'm just curious *why* this itsn't possible. Is it just an oversight, that might be corrected later? Is there a significant problem with this idea that I just didn't think about?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you need a `<select>` _and_ a `<datalist>` with the same `<option>`s? Why?

Comment: This normally is achieved by a programming language, like PHP, Javascript, Java, etc. You have a list of options and you apply it to the desired selects, without duplicity on the code. However, I only see some downloaded bytes for optimization, but I can't see why this will be better performance on browser. Remember that HTML is a tag language, it hasn't variables and control structures.

Comment: I feel like you are shifting your focus on something html itself is not. It's a markup language. If you want features like this you should use the languages made for that. Such as javascript or php.

Comment: I know about this, I'm developing the backend in C#/Asp.NET. I understand that this is not really the job of a markup language, but since it has been made possible for the `<input>` tag, I was just wondering why it isn't possible with the `<option>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is not and will not be possible.

The attribute `list` on `<inputs>`'s is not a valid attribute for `<select>`'s.
[select specs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: _“[…] will not be possible”_ — _[citation needed]_.

Comment: Maybe in 3054 it's possible

Comment: [official w3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)

Comment: the link to "official w3 docs" is relevant only for legacy HTML4. It says "A SELECT element must contain at least one OPTION element.", but HTML4 has always in fact lenient everywhere, and the "must" used there not enforced (allowing *zero* OPTION inner elements). What is requested is a attribute to reference the options (possibly grouped in OPTGROUP elements) that could be stored in another element (SELECT, possibly hidden): the attribute would be some relevant selector to reference the other element (e.g. by id, name or class) to override the inner content of SELECT (which could be empty!)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element) the SELECT element allows *zero* inner elements (OPTION, OPTGROUP, or HR) in its content model. Its attributes are global attributes (id, style, ...), and optional input-specific (name, form, required, size, multiple, disabled, and autocomplete). What is requested is a way to specify the list by reference as an attribute. If not possible as an additional attribute for SELECT, this could be made by insert a single OPTGROUP element as the content of SELECT.

The content model of OPTGROUP also allows empty content, and its input-specific attributes are label (required) and disabled (optional). Such extension is possible using global attributes (like itemid, itemref, itemscope, itemprop...). The required "label" for the external OPTGROUP element would be ignored when this optgroup is referenced by a relevant global attribute of the SELECT element.

In other words, “[…] will not be possible” is false, such extension remains compatible with HTML5 specifications. It's just a matter of current lack of supporting implementation and documentation for the desired behavior, plus some additional validation constraints (may be when an optgroup is used by reference, the internal DOM would have to instantiate a "ghost" element so that elements borrowed by reference would have the correct parent SELECT element.

Comment: Note that the MDN doc for SELECT (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) is wrong in its Technical summary. It says "Permitted content: Zero or more <option> or <optgroup> elements", but forgets "<hr>" elements and script-supporting elements, officially documented in the reference HTML5 specs (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element).

Comment: An interesting way to have the behavior is to use a TEMPLATE element in the content of the hidden SELECT: a template has the interesting property of allowing it to be cloned by a shadow copy, and being itself ignored in the container element. So use <SELECT><TEMPLATE id="mylist"><OPTION/OPTGROUP/HR...></TEMPLATE></SELECT>, then reference that shared list everywhere as <SELECT><OPTGROUP itemref="myid"></SELECT>.

Comment: for now it is still not possible/implemented to use simple referencing attributes in OPTGROUP, but the current fallback is to use a script element as an alternative to <OPTGROUP itemref="myid"> to generate the shadow clone (this is already fully supported and documented in HTML5, describing TEMPLATE elements). Ideally we should be able to use TEMPLATE elements just like A elements: either as a defining container or as a reference (for now HTML5 only supports that model by scripting, something not required for anchor elements).